# Are instance methods ever resolved using static binding?

Tags: java, oop, static, polymorphism

In my lecture notes regarding Static binding, it gives an example using an instance method.

Example:
class Animal has method:

```
void dumb() {int x = 0;}
```

Then

```
Animal doudi = new Animal(); 
doudi.dumb();
```

the compiler can directly insert the body `{int x = 0;}`

However, from what I understand, this isn't a static method, so why is it using static binding as opposed to dynamic binding?

Also, on [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/), it says that instance methods are resolved using dynamic binding.

Is the example here not an instance method?

Comment: You seem to have just _assumed_ that `doudi.dumb();` is resolved with static binding. What made you think that?

Comment: This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901357/697630) contains examples that may extend your investigation of this topic.

Comment: @Sweeper It is written in my lecture notes that it is resolved using static binding, which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 4):

To answer question from title, YES, dynamic binding isn't always applied to instance methods.

There are 3 cases where dynamic binding will not happen when method is called, and that is when method is either:

- `final` - because it can't be overridden in subtype, so compiler is sure which body of method will need to be executed at runtime
- `private` - because private methods are not inherited we can't *override* them. Subtypes can *redeclare* their own method with same name and parameter types (signature) but that will not be considered as overriding (you can't add `@Override` annotation to such method in subtype without compilation error; you *can* change its return type, for instance from `int` to `void`)
- `static` - because it is called on class, not a instance (but that is not the subject of the question. In short, even when you write `someAnimal.staticMethod()` it will be seen by compiler as if you would write `Animal.staticMethod()`)

> ... so why is it using static binding as opposed to dynamic binding

It ISN'T. In your case when you call `doudi.dumb();` compiler sees that `dumb()` is not `final`, `private` nor `static` so it will be subject for polymorphism (so dynamic binding).

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance method !!! For an `method` or `attribute` of class you need explicit use `static` modifier. You are creating an instance of Animal and calling the method `dump()` on this instance. See my example:

```
public class Animal {
    
    static int x = 0; // is an attribute of class
    int y = 0; // is an instance attribute
    
    
    static void myStaticMethod() { // is an method of class
        x++; // increment the class attribute
//      y++; wrong, compilation error !!! y is an instance attribute
    }
    
    void myMethod() { // is an instance method
        y++; // increment the instance attribute
        x++; // increment the class attribute
    }

}
```

Another thing about this is, static attributes/methods are assigned to memory on compilation time, while non-static attributes/methods are assigned to memory on execution time. The life-cycle of static attribute/method starts on program execution and ends at end of execution, instance attribute/method lasts (in Java) while reference count for this instance if above then 0, on reference count is 0 the garbage collector frees the allocated memory for this instance. Look:

```
Animal cat = new Animal();

Animal.myStaticMethod();
cat.myMethod();
        
Animal dog = new Animal();

Animal.myStaticMethod();
dog.myMethod();
dog.myMethod();

System.out.println("Animal::x = " + Animal.x);
System.out.println("cat::y = " + cat.y);
System.out.println("dog::y = " + dog.y);
```

Output is (without y++ on myStaticMethod):

```
Animal::x = 5
cat::y = 1
dog::y = 2
```